# iOS 14 widget: How to ensure that data is current

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget

I have a SwiftUI project in which I'm implementing an iOS 14 widget.

The main app uses iCloud/CloudKit to save the user's stats, and the widget fetches and displays those stats.

What I'm concerned about is that the widget and the main app could get out of sync -- that the widget might display *outdated* stats.

Here's the scenario:

- The user opens the main app and their stats are changed.
- The user closes the main app and finds that the widget hasn't refreshed yet, so it's displaying outdating stats.

**Question:** Is there a recommended strategy for dealing with this scenario -- maybe somehow updating the widget when the main app is closed? I read the documentation -- specifically, [the article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/keeping-a-widget-up-to-date) "Keeping A Widget Up To Date", but I didn't see anything about this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you can [request a widget refresh from your main app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/widgetcenter) with the following code:

```
WidgetCenter.shared.reloadTimelines(ofKind: "com.mygame.gamestatus")
```

This should solve the problem.